# How to get dynamically appended options without using on change or onclick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am adding options dynamically in country select box.Options appears in select box and become selected on click but i want to get them in js as they are appended. If I console select box html in after they are appended. I only got option that is added in html not all other options that are append by js. I am not sure whats going wrong. Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
              <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
                <meta
                  name="viewport"
                  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no"
                />
                <title>login</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
               <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/ionicons.min.css" />

                <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style1.css" />
              </head>
              <body>
                <div class="dashboard" style="text-align: center;">
                  <div class="wrapper">
                    <section id="nav-tabs">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row justify-content-between">
                            <div class="col-8 p-0">
                                <nav>
                                    <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                                        <a class="nav-item nav-link active p-11" id="nav-profil1-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profil1" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true"><span class="word-profile hide">Profile</span> 1</a>
                                    </div>
                                </nav>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-2 align-self-center">
                                 <i class="fa fa-plus plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-2">
                                 <i class="fa fa-cog text-white setting" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                </section>
                <section id="tabs">
                    <div class="container">
                                <div class="row" style="background-color: #013e77;">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 ">
                                <div class="tab-content py-3 px-3 px-sm-0" id="nav-tabContent">
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-profil1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profil1-tab">
                                        <form class="text-center profile" style="color: #757575;" action="#!">
                                              <div class="form-row">
                                                 <div class="form-group col-12">
                                                    <select class="form-control prefer" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="preferred">
                                                      <option>Preferred Profile</option>
                                                      <option value="0">No</option>
                                                      <option value="1">Yes</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                  </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-6">
                                                  <input type="text" class="form-control fname" id="inputfname" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" required>
                                                  <p class="fname-error text-danger hide"></p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-6">
                                                  <input type="text" class="form-control lname" id="inputlname" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" required>
                                                  <p class="lname-error text-danger hide"></p>
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control address" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Address" name="address" required>
                                                <p class="address-error text-danger hide"></p>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control apartment" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, suite, etc. (optional)" name="apartment">
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-row">
                                                <div class="form-group col-12">
                                                  <input type="text" class="form-control city" id="inputCity" placeholder="City" name="city" required>
                                                  <p class="city-error text-danger hide"></p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-4">
                                                  <select id="inputCountry" class="form-control country" name="country">
                                                      <option>--Select Country--</option>
                                                  </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-4">
                                                  <select id="inputState" class="form-control states" name="state">
                                                    <option>--Select State --</option>
                                                  </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-4">
                                                  <input type="text" class="form-control zip" id="inputZip" placeholder="Zip code" name="zip" required>
                                                  <p class="zip-error text-danger hide"></p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-12">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control phone" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Phone"  name="phone" required>
                                                <p class="phone-error text-danger hide"></p>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group col-12">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control card_num" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Card Number" name="card_num" required>
                                                <p class="card_num-error text-danger hide"></p>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group col-12">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control card_name" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Name on Card" name="card_name" required>
                                                <p class="card_name-error text-danger hide"></p>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group col-5">
                                                <input type="date" class="form-control expiry" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Expiration Date" name="expiry" required>
                                                <p class="expiry-error text-danger hide"></p>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group col-4">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control cvv" id="inputAddress" placeholder="CVV" name="cvv" required>
                                                <p class="cvv-error text-danger hide"></p>
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group col-3">
                                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary save">Save</button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-4">
                                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger delete" data-id="">Delete</button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-4">
                                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary update" data-id="">Update</button>
                                            </div>
                                             <div class="form-group col-4">
                                              <button type="button" class="activate"><i class="fa fa-bolt" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                             </div>
                                            </div>
                                            </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            <!-- ./Tabs -->
            </div>
            </div>
                <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                <script src="popup.js"></script>
              </body>
            </html>
```

Here is js:

```
/*----- Dashboard -----*/
              appendCountries();
              console.log($(".country").html());
              /*------get countries from json-----*/
              function appendCountries(){
                  $.getJSON('countries.json',function(result){
                      console.log(result.countries);
                      $.each(result.countries,function(index,country){
                         var option='<option value="'+country.id+"-"+country.name+'">'+country.name+'</option>';
                              $(".country").append(option);

                      });
                  });
              }
```

Thanks in Advance!
I am stuck here please guide me what is the way to get options without adding any event on select box

Answer (score 1):

This happens, because here is some asynchronously actions. If you call `$('.country').html()` after inserting options - it will show you generated html code. It is possible by two ways minimum:

1. Call `$('.country').html()` in the callback of `$.getJSON` after `$.each(...)`.
2. As in my snippet - in processing of Promise of `appendCountries`, but firstly we should return it by adding `return` before `$.getJSON`.

```js
appendCountries().then(() => {
  console.log($(".country").html());
});
/*------get countries from json-----*/

function appendCountries(){
  return $.getJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samayo/country-json/master/src/country-by-name.json',
    function(result){
      // console.log(result);
      $.each(result, function(index, country){
        var option='<option value="'+index+"-"+country.country+'">'+country.country+'</option>';
        $(".country").append(option);
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="countries" id="countriesSelect" class="country">
<option> -- select country -- </option>
</select>
```